# C++ DLL "Cannot Find Entry Point"

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

So I looked at the other questions on SO in regards to this. For some reason I am still getting this issue.

> "Cannot Find Entry Point"

My CPP

```
extern "C"{
    __declspec(dllexport) int GetPose()
    {
        if (currentPose == myo::Pose::none)
            return 0;
        else if (currentPose == myo::Pose::fist)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

My C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("MyoWrapper.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int GetPose();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(100);
    timer.Tick += (sender, args) => 
    {
      int x = GetPose(); 
    };
    timer.Start();
}

}
```

Comment: Perhaps `StdCall` is wrong, since you've not declared it in the C++, and the default calling convetion is `__cdecl`

Comment: I haven't done this in a little while, but if I recall, you need a dllmain function. When you create a new dll project in VS (assuming you're using VS) it should have what's needed. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You probably need `__stdcall` along with `extern "C"` like this: `__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall GetPose();`. Stdcall also has a bit custom name mangling with @X at the end of the function name where X is the size of parameters in bytes as a decimal number. Let's give it a try...

Answer (score 5):

The most likely causes for this error are the following

1. The `GetPos` method is not defined in an `extern "C"` block.  This causes the name to get emitted as a C++ mangled name and hence the name is wrong on the `DllImport` attribute
2. The `MyoWrapper.dll` file is not in the same path as the executable and hence it can't be found

Given that the error is "entry point" I'm going to wager that #1 is the cause.

Comment: Yes this method is within an extern "C" block.

Comment: both of your solutions are implemented and I still receive the error. Any other ideas?

Comment: @amr the next thing I would do is use DLL export viewer to see if the function is actually  being exported

Comment: I figured it out. Answer is below

Answer (score 0):

The solution wasn't to bad.

I am attempting to turn a program with a main into a DLL so obviously the method I wanted to expose wasn't the entry point. Once I exposed all of the methods and set main as the entry point in C# it worked just fine.

```
[DllImport("MyoWrapper.dll", EntryPoint = "main")]
```